# SEO Clean URL for Wordpress 3.x4 on NGINX

Tags: wordpress, url, seo, nginx

I'm trying to make the original url:

http://site.com/test/?p=X

become this:

http://site.com/test/postname

Need to make wordpress recognize the clean URL once the URl is cleaned up.

Any ideas?

Comment: under settings->permalinks set it to postname? or will the htaccess NOT work on your NGINX?

Comment: I got it to work by editing the permalinks settings.  htaccess doesn't work under our nginx server (according to my boss) but he was able to edit the nginx conf file to make the url work.  the url structure looks like this now: www.site.com/postname.  the category is omitted but I'm happy with it.